# Books on understanding Midrash

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, midrash

Anyone know any books or websites or just commentators who delve into and actually try to figure out the deep meaning behind crazy midrashim?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Juggler-King-Conquest-Elaboration-Insights/dp/0873065573

Comment: Ooooh sorry I feel like I am promoting chassidus too much in last 24 hours for a sefardi, but the Chabad Rebbe's spend a huge amount of ink and shiur-time revealing and digging out all the gold from the Midrashim, as well as the deeper meanings of the more interesting and esoteric passages in Tanach, Mishna, Gemara etc. If anyone tells you we don't know what all this stuff means doesn't know about this. Just get a book of Sichot or Ma'amarot from any Lubavitch Rebbe and begin a great journey

Comment: @CuriousYid - are you looking for a compendium or other seforim that give pshat on midrashim?

Comment: @Dov either really

Comment: http://www.urimpublications.com/learning-to-read-midrash.html

Comment: @DoubleAA shame hard to find in UK, looks amazing